# valueForUndefinedKey error

Tags: swift, xcode

Whenever I go from my TableViewController to my ViewController to view the data, I get a terminal error. I'm pretty sure I'm not actually initializing the data somehow, but as I'm new to xCode and Swift I don't exactly know how to fix my issue.

TableViewController (GasManifoldLogSheet) Code

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData

class GasManifoldLogSheet: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {

// MARK: References
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var items = [NSManagedObject]()
var currentIndexPath: NSIndexPath?


// MARK: Random Functions
func viewWillAppear() {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Gas Manifold Logs"
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    fetchData()

}


// MARK: UITableView Data Source

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Message for NSManagedObject counting")
    return items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell
    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = item.valueForKey("date") as? String


    print("Message for NSManagedObject -> Cell name")
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    currentIndexPath = indexPath
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("saveSegue", sender: nil)
}



// MARK: Functions
func fetchData() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "GasManifoldLog")

    do{
        let fetchedResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        items = fetchedResults
    } catch {
        print("error fetching results of search")
    }

}

func initializeFetchedResultsController() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "GasManifoldLog")

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "date", cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
       try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "saveSegue" {

        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let theSelectedRow = [items[indexPath.row]]
        let theDestination = segue.destinationViewController as! GasManifoldLogSheetEdit

        print("All Variables have been set for sending data to the next view controller")

        theDestination.carriedItems = theSelectedRow

        print("Data was sent to the next view controller")
    } else {
        print("prepareForSegue function was called, but the segue identifier was not listed for a saved transition")
    }
    }




}
```

Here's the ViewController (GasManifoldLogSheetEdit) code (I'm only attempting to get one label to actually display the text for now)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class GasManifoldLogSheetEdit: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

// MARK: References
@IBOutlet weak var displayInitials: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displaySIN: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displayRSP: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displaySP: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var displayLSP: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textfieldNotes: UITextField!

var carriedItems = [NSManagedObject]()


// MARK: Functions

override func viewDidLoad() {
displayInitials.text = valueForKey("initials") as? String
}
```

Heres my error code

```
[<EMGS.Users: 0x7fd6e3c264b0> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://91BF1700-C6BD-489A-9886-3BE9404ABE6F/Users/p1> ; data: <fault>), <EMGS.Users: 0x7fd6e3c2f3b0> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://91BF1700-C6BD-489A-9886-3BE9404ABE6F/Users/p2> ; data: <fault>)]
    [<EMGS.Users: 0x7fd6e3c264b0> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://91BF1700-C6BD-489A-9886-3BE9404ABE6F/Users/p1> ; data: {
initials = AA;
loginStatus = 0;
password = A;
username = A;
}), <EMGS.Users: 0x7fd6e3c2f3b0> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://91BF1700-C6BD-489A-9886-3BE9404ABE6F/Users/p2> ; data: <fault>)]
Message for NSManagedObject counting
Message for NSManagedObject counting
Message for NSManagedObject counting
Message for NSManagedObject counting
Message for NSManagedObject -> Cell name
All Variables have been set for sending data to the next view controller
Data was sent to the next view controller
2016-10-18 14:03:44.245 EMGS[76584:1316311] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<EMGS.GasManifoldLogSheetEdit 0x7fd6e3de3ad0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key initials.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a53e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103793deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a53aa9 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x0000000101eaf888 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 226
4   EMGS                                0x00000001014bcc63 _TFC4EMGS23GasManifoldLogSheetEdit11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 211
5   EMGS                                0x00000001014bcec2 _TToFC4EMGS23GasManifoldLogSheetEdit11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 34
6   UIKit                               0x0000000102406f98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
7   UIKit                               0x00000001024072e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27
8   UIKit                               0x0000000102bb1f87 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87
9   UIKit                               0x00000001023d6f62 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133
10  UIKit                               0x0000000102419c8c -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4002
11  UIKit                               0x000000010241cf2c -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 489
12  UIKit                               0x000000010241ca3b -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
13  UIKit                               0x00000001029933e0 __74-[UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 133
14  UIKit                               0x0000000102999f5c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 460
15  UIKit                               0x0000000102999d5f -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
16  UIKit                               0x0000000102409c0c -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 99
17  EMGS                                0x00000001014aa336 _TFC4EMGS19GasManifoldLogSheet9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 182
18  EMGS                                0x00000001014aa3bf _TToFC4EMGS19GasManifoldLogSheet9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 79
19  UIKit                               0x00000001023b3d5e -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1887
20  UIKit                               0x00000001023b3fb3 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 388
21  UIKit                               0x000000010227c4a2 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
22  UIKit                               0x000000010228fc01 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
23  UIKit                               0x000000010229baf3 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010197f367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010197f2d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101974f2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101974828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
28  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000106090ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
29  UIKit                               0x0000000102270610 UIApplicationMain + 171
30  EMGS                                0x00000001014bb20d main + 109
31  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001042a592d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**EDIT 1**
Here is the CoreData model
https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Nd5.jpg

Inside my app, I have a TableView that shows all entries of Gas Manifold Sheets (GasManifoldLogSheet). From that TableView, you can press a create button to access the next ViewController and enter data to create an entity in CoreData. This 2nd ViewController for data entry is called (GasManifoldLogSheetNewRecord). Once the save button is hit, you will be moved back to the original TableView (GasManifoldLogSheet) where you will see a populated list of entities, or Log Sheets.

When I select the individual Log Sheets on my app, It performs a segue to a 3rd ViewController called (GasManifoldLogSheetEdit) where you can view/edit the data.

Whenever I attempt to change the text of the displayInitials by using the value from the key *initials* (inside the viewDidLoad() Function), which by my knowledge should be inside the variable/NSManagedObject *carriedItems*, I get the error I posted above.

**EDIT 2**
Heres the code for the 2nd ViewController (GasManifoldLogSheetNewRecord)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class GasManifoldLogSheetNewRecord: UIViewController {

// MARK: References
@IBOutlet weak var txtDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtSupplyPressure: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtLeftBankPressure: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtRightBankPressure: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtSideInUse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var initials: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtDescription: UITextField!


// MARK: Loading Scripts
func viewWillAppear() {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // Automatic Date
    let currentDate = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
    txtDate.text = convertedDate

    // Automatic Initials
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "loginStatus = %@", "1")

    let results:NSArray = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)

    if(results.count > 0) {
        let res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
        initials.text = res.valueForKey("initials") as? String

    } else {
        print("Login Didn't Work")
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: Opening and closing keyboard

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

@IBAction func backgroundTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view .endEditing(true)
}


// MARK: Functions
@IBAction func btnCreate(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let newGasManifoldLog = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("GasManifoldLog", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    if (txtDate.text!.isEmpty || initials.text!.isEmpty) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:
            "Date and Initials are required.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    newGasManifoldLog.setValue(txtDate.text, forKey: "date")
    newGasManifoldLog.setValue(txtSupplyPressure.text, forKey: "supplyPressure")
    newGasManifoldLog.setValue(txtLeftBankPressure.text, forKey: "leftBankPressure")
    newGasManifoldLog.setValue(txtRightBankPressure.text, forKey: "rightBankPressure")
    newGasManifoldLog.setValue(txtSideInUse.text, forKey: "sideInUse")
    newGasManifoldLog.setValue(initials.text, forKey: "initials")
    newGasManifoldLog.setValue(txtDescription.text, forKey: "jobDescription")

    do {
        try context.save()
        print(newGasManifoldLog)
        print("Object Saved")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

}




/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Comment: Why do you think a key called "initials" is valid?  I don't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: and you need to add in a `super.viewDidLoad()` in your `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad()` method.

Comment: I have updated my question. How do I add a `super.viewDidLoad`? I currently have it set as `override func viewDidLoad()` and attempted to change it to `override func super.viewDidLoad` as well as removing the `override` but I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that I had to downcast the NSManagedObject. Here was my solution that worked

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    for items in carriedItems as [NSManagedObject] {
        print(items)
        displayInitials.text = items.valueForKey("initials") as? String
    }
```

With that code I can now make the values inside my NSManagedObject readable.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message. The crucial part is

> [EMGS.**GasManifoldLogSheetEdit** 0x7fd6e3de3ad0> **valueForUndefinedKey**:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key **initials**.'

Then look for `valueForKey("initials")` in the code which is here:

```
displayInitials.text = valueForKey("initials") as? String
```

As there is no explicit receiver you actually call

```
displayInitials.text = <instance of GasManifoldLogSheetEdit>.valueForKey("initials") as? String
```

which of course crashes.

---

You should declare `carriedItems` as a single object

```
var carriedItem = NSManagedObject!
```

and pass the item in `prepareForSegue`

```
let theSelectedRow = items[indexPath.row]
...
theDestination.carriedItem = theSelectedRow
```

Now you can write

```
displayInitials.text = carriedItem.valueForKey("initials") as? String
```

As mentioned in the comments it's recommended to call `super` in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad
   ...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do, except it would tell me that there isn't a member "initials" for the NSManagedObject